# I get no response scraping a "google maps" map using scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape this webpage:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=10gfc4vm6VKjxIf6UhKLlMLePqTjTYXYC&ll=50.65039081184933%2C3.040291506005474&z=11
to get information about producers.
However, when I send my requests (through scrapy shell) I get an empty response:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=10gfc4vm6VKjxIf6UhKLlMLePqTjTYXYC&ll=50.6503908118493%2C3.040291506005474&z=11"
In [1]: response
```

Here is the code I am using

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import re
import scrapy

from aprobio.items import AprobioItem


class AprospiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aprospider'
    allowed_domains = ['aprobio.fr']
    start_urls = ['http://aprobio.fr/']

    crawl_datetime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.crawler.stats.set_value("start_time", self.start_time)
        data = re.findall(r"var _pageData = = (.+?);\r", response.body.decode("utf-8"), re.S)
```

Comment: Can you just export the KML?

Comment: page uses JavaScript to add data on page but Scrapy can't run javascript. You may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript. But first check if you can get it with GoogleAPI and you get it as JSON or XML and you don't have to scrape it.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
You change ROBOTSTXT_OBEY to False in settings.py